# Where Am I in Listview Android?

Tags: android, listview

I use Listview with Remote Control (Q1 Himedia SettopBOx)
Now down and up keydown ،How do I know where I am in listview
for example: when arrived in last item in listview then list refreshed or going to first item?

Please Help Me....
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) of ListView. You can set a new callback using `ListView.setOnScrollListener()` and get first visible item position and number of visible entries by implementing `onScroll` function of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) for the listview like so.

```
myListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
            {
                // Your code goes here. Determine the position with the firstVisibleItem.
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
            {
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is flinging through the view");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks friends..How Find Last Item in Listview? which method is used for find it?

Comment: If the sum of the first visible item and the visible item count equals the total number of items, your user can see the last row. There is no method for it. Its Math.

Comment: int loadedItems = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
Now.how can wite: if(statement){ }  //for reload listview

Comment: if (loadedItems == totalItemCount) {}

Comment: @Override
   public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int loadedItems = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                
              /*  if(firstVisibleItem==loadedItems)
                {
                 mChannelsListView.setSelection(0);
                }*/
                if (loadedItems == totalItemCount) {
                 
     mChannelsListView.setSelection(0);

                }  //// i use this code but this method Called several times..

Comment: It will be called every time the user scrolls the view. You will need to take care of that.

Comment: I worked with Your code But Problem Not Soloved.....if (loadedItems == totalItemCount) {}  when down with remote Key just 1 item is down and canot work on other item.